# Runtime error codes on AsyncPostback from AJAX toolkit

Tags: asp.net, ajax, runtime-error, ajax.net, asyncpostbackerror

I'm interested in the meaning of the runtime error codes come from asp.net ajax
like.

```
110|error|500|d:\ *PATH* \SomeControl.ascx(5): error CS1026: ) expected|
```

Does anybody knows where are can i find list of error codes with the meanings or has someone a collection?

Maybe it's a very general error i will figure out nothing from it but it's a "nice to know" thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your control isn't compiling.  Make sure you build your web site or solution.

> An incomplete statement was found.
>
> A common cause of this error is
>   placing a statement, rather than an
>   expression, within an inline
>   expression in an ASP.NET page. For
>   example, the following is incorrect

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tc5zwdf7%28VS.71%29.aspx) for more detail.

Comment: I already figured out what was the problem,Thanks for help. :)
The link posted by David Basarad contains the link for runtime error codes,so will mark as answer!
Thanks for the link again!